# NSPoint as dictionary index

Tags: objective-c

I need to have data structure, each element in which is accessible by pair of (x,y) (like nspoint).

I can store them in NSDictionary with keys like @"8,10", but I'm looking for more elegant and efficient solution (I don't want to have two dimensional array cause I want to have O(1) access to elements by coordinate)

Comment: Don't forget you have `NSStringFromCGPoint(CGPoint point)` and `CGPointFromString(NSString *string)` to make the conversion easier

Comment: How would using a two dimensional array not be O(1) access?  And how could constructing and comparing string or NSValue keys from two integers not totally swamp the lookup time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `NSValue` as key (`+NSValue valueWithCGPoint:` see [this link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/NSValue_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html)), might be a bit 'lighter'. Otherwise, if the values is the x and y pair have some limit, like e.g. 256 for x, 256 for y, you could use bit masks where the first 8 bits indicate the x value and the second 8 bits the y value (since 256 = 2^8).